# Group records by day including days in between that contain no records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have to display how many votes were issued on each day (from the first vote, until the last vote) users voted for poll **2**.

My current query works fine; but I'm having trouble when a specific day doesn't have any votes in it. For example, for poll **2**, this should be the result:

- **May, 11 2017 = 1**
- May, 12 2017 = 0
- May, 13 2017 = 0
- May, 14 2017 = 0
- May, 15 2017 = 0
- May, 16 2017 = 0
- **May, 17 2017 = 1**
- May, 18 2017 = 0
- May, 19 2017 = 0
- **May, 20 2017 = 2**

...but instead I'm getting this:

- May, 11 2017 = 1
- May, 17 2017 = 1
- May, 20 2017 = 2

So, what I need is that all days that contain no records (between the first and last vote) also appear in the results. This is my current query:

```
SELECT DATE(poll_vote.date_insert) AS date_insert,
COUNT(poll_vote.id_vote) AS q
FROM poll_vote WHERE poll_vote.id_poll = 2
GROUP BY DATE(date_insert) ORDER BY date_insert
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eebc6b/1) with the example data. Thanks!

Comment: Aside from the '2'/'3' confusion, this is really a display issue. Consider handling issues of data display in application code, e.g. a bit of PHP if that's available.

Comment: @Strawberry i fixed the 2/3 issue, thanks for noticing. Yeah, doing it php was definitely an alternative, but i wanted to know if it could be done easier in mysql.

Comment: It can be done in MySQL, but not more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry), I ended up writing a solution in php instead of mysql. For anyone interested, here's the code.

This solution only returns 0 in 1 day in between blank dates because that's what I needed. Example:

- May, 11 2017 = 1
- May, 16 2017 = 0
- May, 17 2017 = 1
- May, 19 2017 = 0
- May, 20 2017 = 2

That allows me to display a trending line chart just like this one:[image]

```
$sql = 'SELECT DATE(poll_vote.date_insert) AS date_insert, COUNT(poll_vote.id_vote) AS q FROM poll_vote WHERE poll_vote.id_poll = :id_poll GROUP BY DATE(date_insert) ORDER BY date_insert';

$stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);
if($id_poll) $stmt->bindValue(':id_poll', $id_poll, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

# insert blank dates between existing dates
$hotness = array();
foreach($data as $item) {
    if(!$temp) {
        $temp = $item['date_insert'];
    } else {
        $date_past = new DateTime($temp);
        $date_now = new DateTime($item['date_insert']);
        $diff = $date_now->diff($date_past)->format("%a");
        if($diff > 1) {
            $date_new = new DateTime($item['date_insert']);
            $date_new->modify('-1 day');
            $hotness[] = array(
                'date_insert' => $date_new->format('Y-m-d'),
                'q' => 0
            );
        }
    }
    $hotness[] = array(
        'date_insert' => $item['date_insert'],
        'q' => $item['q']
    );
}

# final result
print_r($hotness);
```